# ESS language modes with use-package

Tags: use-package, ess

I've recenly started to convert my `init.el` to using `use-package`, and have so far not found any problems with that -- except that I can't get ESS to work for all languages.

I have installed the package `ess` from Melpa. If I don't mention this at all in the init file, normal ".r" files get opened with `ess-mode` (showing as up as `ESS[S]`) as major mode, so there seems to be some automatic configuration going on. ".Rnw" files, on the other hand, don't get opened in ESS. Additionally, I want to use `julia-mode` in ESS (which is supposed to work [automatically](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/wiki/Julia); the `julia-mode` package is also installed). So I added the following:

```
(use-package ess
  :mode (("\\.[rR]\\'" . R-mode)
         ("\\.[rR]nw\\'" . Rnw-mode)
         ("\\.jl\\'" . julia-mode)))
```

However, this does not help anything. When opening a ".jl" file, there is no `julia` function available, as there should; and there's always a warning

> File mode specification error: (error Autoloading failed to define
>   function Rnw-mode)

So, how am I supposed to set that up? I see that in most [documentations](http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#Installation), ESS mode is compiled by hand and loaded by `(require 'ess-site)` -- does that make the difference?

I'm using Emacs 25.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file associations should all be set up for you. It works for me on Emacs 25.1 with just the following in my init:

```
(use-package ess
  :init (require 'ess-site))
```

This will set the associations for R-mode, julia-mode and Rnw-mode. If that doesn't work for you, the most likely explanation is that something else in your configuration is causing the problem (ie., by changing the assocations with R-mode etc).

Comment: Works, great! I hadn't thought of using _both_ `use-package` and `require`...

Comment: It can be a bit tricky getting the more complex packages like ESS loaded at the correct time in your init sequence!