# Install ESS with use-package

Tags: use-package, ess

I would like to install the emacs speaks statistics package from melpa.
I found the following snipped

```
  (use-package ess
  :init (require 'ess-site))
```

on this side https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/29740/14419 .

but get the following error:

```
Error (use-package): ess :init: Cannot open load file: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden, ess-site
```

I have used 'use-package successfully to install other packages and have the following path in my config

```
;;; Standard package repositories
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org-plus-contrib" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("elpy" . "https://jorgenschaefer.github.io/packages/"))
```

I'm using emacs 25.1.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was missing ':ensure t .
Now the ess package gets automatically installed at first use.

For more information on how to load packages from ELPA with package.el and use-package see: https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package

```
 (use-package ess
  :ensure t
  :init (require 'ess-site))
```

Answer (score 1):

That snippet doesn't install `ESS`, it loads it after you've already installed it. To install it, try the following:

`M-x package-install-packages`

This will open the list of packages available. Find ess and type `i` to mark it for installation. Then type `x` to install it.

Comment: Thanks for looking in to this question, I didn't have the karma comment on you other solution. I wanted 'use-package to do the installing automatically but forgot the command 'ensure: t.

Comment: Searching for ess will give multiple hits! which to choose?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen the package is just called "ess" If you you use MELPA it should give you a newer version than Marmalade.